# How to loop through a vector of data frame names to print first columns of the df's?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, sapply

so x is a vector. i am trying to print the first col of df's name's saved in the vector.  so far I have tried the below but they don't seem to work.

```
x = (c('Ethereum,another Df..., another DF...,'))

for (i in x){
  print(i[,1])
}

sapply(toString(Ethereum), function(i) print(i[1]))
```

Comment: Not really clear what you need. Please give an example with expected output

Comment: imagine x is vector where each item is a name of a data frame. now I want to print the first colm of each data frame. i would have to go df[,1] to print for each one. now imagine the vector has 100 data frame names. how would you print the first colm of each? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Your vector is a single string not a vector. Likely something like `strsplit(',', x)[[1]][1]` is what you're seeking. Or `get(strsplit(',', x)[[1]][1])[, 1]`

Comment: its a vector -> x = c('Bitcoin','Tether','etc')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
x <- c('Ethereum','anotherDf',...)

for (i in x){
  print(get(i)[,1])
}
```

Comment: Geez get(i) ...dang, y didnt i think of that. your kung-fu is strong. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mget` to get data in a list and using `lapply` extract the first column of each dataframe in the list.

```
data <- lapply(mget(x), `[`, 1)
#Use `[[` to get it as vector. 
#data <- lapply(mget(x), `[[`, 1)
```

Similar solution using `purrr::map` :

```
data <- purrr::map(mget(x), `[`, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks mota bhai..:)